# UI / UX designer tool with custom style

Tags: user-interface, user-experience, ui-design, sketchflow

My clients have their home grown style sheets for buttons, labels, alerts etc for consistent look across their applications.

Now if I want to create high fidelity mockups for client review, is there a way to generate mockups using the styles sheet they have?

Any tools like Adobe / Sketch can do the same?

Appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Figma is a great tool which helps us to build a master template of certain UI component and use it across the prototype wherever it's needed. Similarly, you can use Adobe XD and Sketch which also have similar kind of features also.

Comment: Thank you @Rupam. I ended up doing Adobe XD.